# XOR operation with "use integer" gives different values on Windows and Linux

Tags: perl, 32bit-64bit

Why am I getting different results for the XOR expression `0 ^ 2506133561` under the `use integer` pragma on Windows and Linux?

Windows:

```
perl -e "use integer; print 0^2506133561"
-1788833735
```

Linux:

```
perl -e 'use integer; print 0^2506133561'
2506133561
```

Comment: 64 bit windows 7 and rhel 6 64 bit

Answer (score 4):

Your Perl interpreter on Windows very likely uses 32-bit integers, while the one you're using on Linux has 64-bit ints.

To test this, run the shell command:

```
perl -V:ivsize
```

on each system.  It should print `ivsize='4'` on 32-bit perls, and `ivsize='8'` on 64-bit perls.  You can also obtain this information in a Perl script using `$Config{ivsize}` from the [Config](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html) module.

To force the result of a bit operation to be interpreted as a signed 32-bit number even on 64-bit perls, you can use [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

```
$num = unpack "l", pack "l", $num;
```

Alternatively, you can use simple bit operations and arithmetic like mpapec suggests:

```
$num &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
$num -= 2**32 if $num >= 2**31;
```

Comment: thanks for you reply ..
 The problem is with perl in windows which is 32 bit.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -e "use bigint; print 0^2506133561;"
```

output should be `2506133561` regardless of perl version (32vs64 bit)

From [perldoc integer](http://perldoc.perl.org/integer.html)

> Finally, use integer; also has an additional affect on the bitwise operators. Normally, the operands and results are treated as unsigned integers, but with use integer; the operands and results are signed. This means, among other things, that ~0 is -1, and -2 & -5 is -6.

If you want to force signed integers, you can perform additional calculation,

```
my $n = 0^2506133561;
$n -= 2**32 if $n >>31;
```

Comment: thankyou very much.
The problem is with perl in windows which is 32 bit.